# Вывести предложения, содержащие заданное пользователем слово

Tags: c++, файлы, char

Это должна быть программа, которая считывает текст из файла и выводит на экран только те предложения, которые содержат введенное пользователем слово. Как сделать так, чтобы при перезаписи предложений в файл output.txt каждое в новую строку, предложение считало разделителем не только точку, но и ! и ?
И как сделать так, чтобы слово Dad, например, в начале предложения с заглавной буквы считалось одним и тем же словом с "dad" введенным с клавиатуры

````
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void copySentencesToFile(const char* inputFilename, const char* outputFilename) {
    ifstream inputFile(inputFilename);
    ofstream outputFile(outputFilename);

    if (!inputFile.is_open() || !outputFile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Ошибка открытия файла" << endl;
        return;
    }

    char sentence[200];
    char ch;
    int sentenceIndex = 0;
    while (inputFile.get(ch)) {
        if (ch == '.') {
            sentence[sentenceIndex] = ch;
            sentence[sentenceIndex + 1] = '\0'; // добавляем завершающий нулевой символ
            outputFile << sentence << endl;
            sentenceIndex = 0; // сбрасываем индекс для следующего предложения
        }
        else {
            sentence[sentenceIndex] = ch;
            sentenceIndex++;
        }
    }

    inputFile.close();
    outputFile.close();
}

int IsWordInSentence() {
    char ch[256];
    ifstream input("output.txt");
    if (!input.is_open()) {
        cout << "Невозможно открыть файл" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    char* a = new char[256];
    cout << "Введите искомое слово: ";
    cin.getline(a, 256);
    int k = 0;
    while (!input.eof()) {
        input.getline(ch, 256);
        if (strstr(ch, a)) {
            cout << ch << endl;
            k++;
        }
    }
    if (k == 0) {
        cout << "Такого предложения нет " << endl;
    }
}



int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    const char* inputFilename = "text.txt";
    const char* outputFilename = "output.txt";

    copySentencesToFile(inputFilename, outputFilename);
    IsWordInSentence();

    return 0;

}```
````

Comment: Я бы переводил все сразу в верхний, например, регистр. Потом искал подстроку - из искомого слова, и смотрел, что от нее слева и справа. Буквы? Это не слово, а часть. Не буквы? значит, слово. Подстроку, понятно, искал бы в цикле - чтоб найти все вхождения...

Answer (score 0):

> предложение считало разделителем не только точку, но и ! и ?

Для этого можно добавить в условие проверки через оператор `or` сравнение со всеми знаками по мимо `ch == '.'`
Что же касается всего кода, его можно значительно улучшить с помощью STL контейнеров и библиотеки algorithm.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

inline bool is_space(const char &c) {
    return c == ' ';
}

inline bool is_sign(const char &c) {
    return (c == '.') or (c == '!') or (c == '?');
}

inline bool is_sign_or_space(const char &c) {
    return is_sign(c) or is_space(c);
}

int findSentencesWithFragment(const char *inputPath, const char *outputPath, const std::string &prompt) {
    
    std::ifstream input(inputPath);
    std::ofstream output(outputPath);
    if (input.bad() or output.bad()) {
        std::cout << "Невозможно открыть файл" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // строка, содержащая в себе текст из входящего файла в кодировке UTF-8
    std::string str(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{input}, {});

    // итератор на начало строки
    auto it_begin = str.begin();
    while (it_begin != str.end()) {
        // find_if вернёт итератор либо на . ! ?, либо на str.end()
        auto it_end = std::find_if(it_begin, str.end(), is_sign);
        if (it_end != str.end()) {
            // ищем слово в предложении
            auto shift = std::string(it_begin, ++it_end).find(prompt);

            // проверяем наличие слова в предложении и пробела после
            if (shift != std::string::npos) {
                // выводим в консоль предложение с найденным словом и записываем его в файл
                std::cout << std::string(it_begin, it_end) << std::endl;
                output << std::string(it_begin, it_end);
            }
            // пропускаем пробелы в начале предложения
            it_end = std::find_if_not(it_end, str.end(), is_space);
        }
        it_begin = it_end;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    // меняет кодировку cout на UTF-8, поддерживающий все языки мира
    // проверьте кодировку выших файлов, она также должна быть UTF-8, иначе текст будет искажён 
    std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));

    // к сожалению cin выдаст ASCII последовательность
    // поэтому пока что обойдёмся поиском, заданным в коде
    return findSentencesWithFragment("text.txt", "output.txt", "Фраза, слово или буква");
}
```

Правда в этой реализации не учитывается случай, когда слово в составе другого слова, но это также можно исправить при использовании std::find, где предикатом будет служить поиск слова с пробелом или символом на конце.

Comment: Также, если вы хотите вести поиск без учёта регистра, сначала вам нужно преобразовать весь текст, включая запрос, в верхний/нижний регистр. Это можно сделать используя словарь замены в простом случае (но вы не пропишите его для всех букв на свете и врядли напишете эффективно), либо использовать библиотеки, на подобии International Components for Unicode (ICO). В последнем случае вы получите функцию с поддержкой большого числа языков мира.